# Java with Intellij idea. error: package com.mysql.cj.jdbc does not exist. Why Intellij shows "no problems" but when click on "run" I get this error?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I know that this question is asked many times, but I just can't find any solution that can work for me.

I want to add mysql connector library to my java project.

```
package org.example;

import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
import org.example.db.MySQLAccess;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySQLAccess dao = new MySQLAccess();
        try {
            //dao.readDataBase();
            Driver driver = new Driver();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, at first Intellij Idea shows with red letters that it can't resolve "import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;"  It's understandable. So I try to fix it with the following steps:

Right Click on project -> Open Module Settings -> Modules -> main -> Add -> JARs or Directories ->  scope{compile} -> Apply
Project structures -> Libraries -> Add

After this. The red lines are gone, it seems like it must now work but when I click on "run" I get  this error:

```
C:\Java_Projects\TestingCombinations\src\main\java\org\example\Main.java:3: error: package com.mysql.cj.jdbc does not exist


import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
```

Interesting right? See the screen below what I see before the "run" click:

[image]

How I can fix this problem? What Ideas do you have?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the driver on the classpath when compiling, or you have a 5.1.x version on the classpath instead of the 8.0.x. As an aside, doing `new Driver()` is not the idiomatic way to load a JDBC driver. Either you rely on automatic driver loading, or you should use `Class.forName` to load the driver.

Comment: The driver is deprecated from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. But I use the com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. But anyway, that's not the problem. I wrote the Driver driver = new Driver(); just for testing purposes. Testing if library has added to my project successfully or not. And as I see, Intellij idea shows it as successful but in fact java don't see the needed classes!

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?